# When and why did male formal attire in the West become uniform?

Tags: clothing, western-civilisation

It *seems to **me*** (maybe I am wrong?!) that the formal attire for men in the West has been uniform (as in "bland", not "military") for at least 100 years.

While moderately evolving in time, at any given moment the men style is fixed: a suite, a collared shirt, and a tie. The only variety are the colors of the shirt and tie (and, possibly, the number of buttons on the suite). Just look at an official political function, and you see men dressed identically, at least compared to the variety of women's styles.

On the other hand, it seems that 400 years ago men were allowed more stylistic variety (at least Dumas seems to spend as much time describing men's attire as women's).

**When and Why did the change happen?**

Related discussions that contain no relevant information:

- [ELI5: Why has the style of male formal attire remained relatively unchanged for the past 150 years, while casual clothes have changed dramatically?](https://www.reddit.com/r/explainlikeimfive/comments/3wnurp/eli5_why_has_the_style_of_male_formal_attire/)
- [Why did Men's fashion become plain, colorless and so uniform after 1800?](https://www.quora.com/Why-did-Mens-fashion-become-plain-colorless-and-so-uniform-after-1800)

PS. I want to explicitly exclude from consideration "peacock" events like Oscars.

**This question is completely answered by [Great Male Renunciation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Male_Renunciation)**: French revolution and Sans-culottes.

Comment: My preliminary research is seeing photos of men dresses uniformly and women dressed variously and reading descriptions of men and women dressed variously.

Comment: A notable exception certainly occurred starting in the early 1970's when multicoloured (particularly pastel) tuxedos were common for wedding parties and [leisure suits](https://www.vintag.es/2018/09/leisure-suits-1970s.html).

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: please see PS.

Comment: Never mind peacock events - these tuxedos were popular amongst young tradesmen I knew at that time. Leisure suits were all the rage at clubs like Studio 54 for a time, not just in NYC and Cannes but all across North America at least.

Comment: As for the why, Pierre Bourdieu's [Distinction: A Social Critique of the Judgement of Taste](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distinction_(book)) seems to contain some investigation into this. Summarized by WP: "the cultural tastes of the dominant (ruling) class tend to dominate the tastes of the other social classes, forcing individual men and women of economically and culturally dominated classes to conform to the dominating aesthetic preferences, or risk "societal" (but in fact, fractional and domineering) disapproval – appearing crude, vulgar and tasteless."

Comment: I think https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Male_Renunciation and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_tie provide some answers

Comment: @CarlosMartin - thank you, you answered my question.

Comment: Would imagine that in person business meetings across borders, enabled by trains and later planes, would accelerate that